# How to remove/uninstall gitlab-runner completely from centos

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api, runner

My gitlab-runner service is not running no matter what I do. I used to have same problem before and when I used to update, and it used to start running but now it’s not starting at all.

I have uninstalled and then again installed it’s still the same. I guess I am not uninstalling/removing completely. How to uninstall gitlab runner completely or how to start service?

I also don’t get home dir of gitlab-runner. when I say gitlab-runner list I get following config details.

```
ConfigFile=/home/rohith/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

but I try cd to gitlab-runner user dir I don't find the dir at all.

Comment: You do know that .gitlab-runner and gitlab-runner are not the same thing? Also, files & directories starting with dot are hidden from a lot of things by default.

Answer (score 64):

If you install gitlab runner binary on Ubuntu  20.04 you can uninstall it completely by run below commands:

```
# Stop and remove the service
sudo gitlab-runner stop
sudo gitlab-runner uninstall
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# Remove gitlab-runner files and config
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
sudo userdel gitlab-runner
sudo rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/
```

Comment: This still leaves the systemd unit file potentially...

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski In my case (centos 7), following the above steps didn't leave any systemd zombie service : 
`systemctl | grep gitlab`

Comment: Initially I saw gitlab runner service, after `systemctl daemon-reload` It have removed (version 16.7). Apparently it removes files but doesn't do reload for you. (I'm glad it doesn't run for me, I believe it's good choice)

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu/Debian** users, newer versions of `gitlab-runner` on Ubuntu are managed via a `.deb` file, so this should do the trick:

`sudo apt remove gitlab-runner`

Answer (score -2):

first:

`sudo apt remove gitlab-runner`
`rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab`

Kill all process:
`pkill -f gitlab`

then:
`rm -rf /opt/gitlab rm -rf /etc/gitlab rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab`

Comment: AFAIK, you are removing the whole gitlab folder with `rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab`, `rm -rf /opt/gitlab`, `rm -rf /etc/gitlab` and `rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab`. This is not what was asked

Comment: This answer is dangerous [DO NOT RUN IT UNLESS YOU WANT TO REMOVE GITLAB]

Comment: Lol such a nice answer :))